# MPEG-DASH: generating a single mpd and corresponding segments for multi-bitrate videos

Tags: mpeg-dash, dashcast

Hi I have a single video which is re-encoded to various bit rates.
I have generated the corresponding mpd file also.It plays using MP4Client.
I used the following command:

```
MP4Box -dash 4000 -frag 4000 -rap -profile onDemand -segment-name %s/segment_ -url-template -out manifest.mpd  video-240.mp4#video video-360.mp4#video video-480.mp4#video video-720.mp4#video video-audio.mp4#audio
```

But it generates only a single segment for each bit rate.I want to generate the corresponding segments(i.e segment list) also for all the bit rates.

Any help will be really useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set the profile to simple and now it works!